# ¿Cómo conocer el algoritmo utilizado para codificar una password en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, encriptación

Tengo una base de datos SQL Server con contraseñas de usuario codificadas, la cual alimenta actualmente otro sistema desarrollado por externos.

Necesito utilizar esta misma base de datos y contraseñas para alimentar un nuevo sistema y su respectivo login, pero no consigo averiguar cuál es el algoritmo de codificación que se utiliza en la base de datos. No puedo tampoco acceder al código fuente del sistema externo, probé comparando con MD5 y SHA1 sin conseguir resultados.

Este es un ejemplo de contraseña almacenada:

```
sha1$c107c$2a382bee4c041b4309139787ef8146acbe751c62
```

equivale al texto `alba2018`

Agradezco mucho sus respuestas.

Comment: Encontré un artículo, Espero te ayude: Fuente: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El formato se puede dividir en varios fragmentos, separados por `$`:

- `sha1` es el algoritmo
- `c107c` es la *sal* (salt) a concatenar delante de la contraseña antes de hacer el hash
- `2a382bee4c041b4309139787ef8146acbe751c62` es el resultado de `sha1('c107c'+'alba2018')`

Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md)

Comment: Por completar tu respuesta, añadir que el hash es el resultado de concatenar la sal + la contraseña y aplicarle el sha1. Se puede probar en algun sitio online como por ejemplo [Sha1 online](http://www.sha1-online.com/), poniendo como texto `c107calba2018`

Comment: Sería genial si nos das algún enlace de referencia por favor, para seguir aprendiendo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a @Pablo-Lozano Era lo que necesitaba!!!

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh! Excelente complemento